# How does one update/create bibliography for a doc in Texmaker?

Tags: bibtex, texmaker

I'm looking for the procedure to place entries into a bibliography for a document in Texmaker.  I have an existing `.bib` file with references in it as well as a document that correctly references the entries I have.  If I create a new entry and use the `\cite{}` call I am unable to get the references into the document.  Instead of a number reference in the document I get a `[??]` and no entry in the bibliography.  I believe I have to run BibTeX at some point before QuickBuild, but I cannot figure out the order of what I am supposed to run.  I also cannot find any documentation that outlines how this is supposed to work.

Comment: Do you have `\bibliographystle{<style-name>}` and `\bibliography{<bib-file-name>}` in your `latex` file? Then you have to run `latex->bibtex->latex`

Comment: That order/procedure worked!  You should make this an answer so I can give you points!  Thanks!

Comment: Believe it or not, the name of the TeX front-end you're using is “Texmaker”. `;-)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a bibliography and references to it one has to insert

```
\bibliographystyle{<style-name>}
```

somewhere in the latex source file and

```
\bibliography{<bib-file>}
```

where the bibliography should appear. Then, run `latex->bibtex->latex` (in some cases further runs of `latex` are needed to stabilize cross-references.