# Bibdesk citing [?] instead of a proper citation

Tags: biblatex, bibdesk

new to LaTeX and BibDesk. Hoping to somehow figure out how to get it to work!

I've entered all the required information into a bib file called Chapterbib.bib and saved it in the same folder as my file. In order to cite a source in my document, I copy the citation key into my document where I'd like to cite a source - however, rather than putting a citation in I simply get [?] after my sentence. I'm not sure what sort of packages or commands I should be using so any advice as to how to get moving from here would be much appreciated. Thank you for your help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/32374)! Can you please post a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/32374) starting at `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`? It will really help us to help you! In general, you need to run a separate program (e.g. `biber` or `bibtex`) and then `latex` or `pdflatex` again to get the citations properly inserted, but you've not given enough information for us to help you.

Comment: See here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136898/32374

Comment: Which editor do you use? (TeXShop, TeXworks, Texmaker, TeXStudio, Emacs, Vim, something else) In TeXshop for example, you first select LaTeX and click *Typeset* to compile, then you select BibTeX and click *Typeset*, and finally select LaTeX again, and compile twice. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133742/586 for some screenshots. TeXworks has a similar interface.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple ! First of all, you have to mention some parameters. You have to choose the bibliography style, like `apalike`, and then point to your `.bib` file using the command `\bibliography`. No need to put `.bib` file in the current folder :

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{/Users/../LibraryBibDesk.bib}
```

Now you have to **cite** in your article using for example : `\cite{Rolf-Adams:1994aa}`.

When you finish, you have to compile your `.tex` file and use BibTeX as follow :

1. LaTeX
2. BibTeX
3. LaTeX
4. LaTeX

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for your help! If you don't mind, may I ask what BibTex is? I don't really understand the four step process you've put down after your comments.

Comment: @user51838 BibTeX is an additional program that is used to tell (La)TeX what to put in the places you see `[?]`. See here for more info, and also see the question I linked above: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Getting_current_LaTeX_document_to_use_your_.bib_file 

If you have a question about how to set up your IDE to run `bibtex`, that is a different question and you should 1) search if there is an answer already, 2) look at the documentation for your IDE and 3) if you still can't do it, ask a new question. Hope it helps!