# Bibliography not working

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I have a bibliography file called `sources_robot.bib` containing an entry with cite key `Dwengoboard`. When I want to cite it in a Latex file, this does not work. Can somebody suggest where the problem might be?
MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Test}
Test \cite{Dwengoboard}

\bibliographystyle{abbrvurl}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}\bibliography{sources_robot}

\end{document}
```

Outcome:

[image]

Comment: have you run bibtex ?

Comment: I edit the .bib file in BibDesk.

Comment: See here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136898/32374

Comment: You need to run the bibtex program on your document after you have used latex, and then run latex again twice after bibtex has generated the bibliography